# exponential equation with a sum of exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the following exponential equation:

$e^{2x} - e^{x+3} - e^{x + 1} + e^4 = 0$

According to the the text I am using the answer should be $x = 1,3$ but I can't derive the appropriate quadratic $x^2 -4x + 3$ from the above equation using any of the methods I know. Can someone point me in the right direction? Is there a substitution I'm not seeing?

Comment: Have you tried to turn this into a quadratic, using a change of variable?

Comment: Your textbook is wrong. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%282x%29-e%5E%28x%2B3%29-ex%2B1%2Be%5E4%3D0).

Comment: How about the substitution $\mathrm{e}^x=u$?

Comment: @Bo Schmidt: that was my idea too; great minds think alike, I guess ;).

Comment: I screwed up the original equation - the third term should have been raised to the power of $x-1$. Thanks for the link to Wolfram - it is giving 1 and 3 as solutions for the corrected equation [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%282x%29-e%5E%28x%2B3%29-e%5E%28x%2B1%29%2Be%5E4%3D0) and it's also giving me a hint on how to solve the problem - very useful.

Comment: @DBFdalwayse: Haha, for sure! :)

Comment: Maybe writing it as $e^{2x}-(e^3+e^1)e^x+e^4$ will let you see a factorization. Or maybe writing it as $e^x(e^x-e^3)-e^1(e^x-e^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$e^{2x} - e^{x+3} - e^{x + 1} + e^4 = 0$$

$$\left(e^{x+1}\right)\left(e^{2x-\left(x+1\right)}-e^{\left(x+3\right)-\left(x+1\right)}-e^{\left(x+1\right)-\left(x+1\right)}+e^{4-\left(x+1\right)}\right)=0$$

$$\left(e^{x+1}\right)\left(e^{x-1}-e^{2}-e^{0}+e^{3-x}\right)=0$$

$$\left(e^{x+1}\right)\left(e^{x-1}-e^{2}-1+e^{3-x}\right)=0$$

$$\left(e^{x+1}\right)\left(e^{-x-1}\right)\left(e^x-e\right)\left(e^x-e^3\right)=0$$

$$e^0 \cdot \left(e^x-e\right)\left(e^x-e^3\right) =0$$

$$\left(e^x-e\right)\left(e^x-e^3\right)=0$$

Thus, either $e^x-e=0$ or $e^x-e^3 = 0$. These correspond to $x=1$ or $x=3$.

Comment: thanks for the answer - I was trying to go this way but it never occurred to me to try and introduce the $e^{x+1}$ term.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{2x} - (e^3 +e)e^x + e^4$$

Let $m = e^x$

$$m^2- (e^3 + e)m + e^4$$

$a = 1$, $b=-(e^3 + e)$, $c =e^4$

$$m = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} = \frac{(e^3 + e) \pm \sqrt{{(-(e^3 + e))}^2 -4(1)(e^4)}}{2(1)}$$

$$= \frac{(e^3 + e) \pm \sqrt{e^6 +e^2 + 2e^4 - 4e^4}}{2}$$

$$= \frac{(e^3 + e) \pm \sqrt{e^4 +1 + 2e^2 - 4e^2} \sqrt{e^2}} {2}$$

$$= \frac{(e^3 + e) \pm \sqrt{e^4 - 2e^2 + 1} \sqrt{e^2}} {2}$$

$$= \frac{(e^3 + e) \pm \sqrt{(e^2 - 1)^2} \cdot e} {2}$$

$$=\frac{e^3 + e \pm e^2 - 1 \cdot e}{2}$$

$$=\frac{e^3 + e \pm (e^3 -e)}{2}$$

$$m = \frac{e^3 +e + e^3 - e}{2}, \frac{e^3 + e - e^3 + e}{2}$$

$$\implies m = \frac{2e^3}{2}, \frac{2e}{2}$$

$$m = e^3, e$$

But $m= e^x$

$$e^x = e^3, e^x =e$$

Since the bases are the same, you can equate $x = 1,3$

Comment: this is a nice answer but I'm going with Zubin's - his factoring method feels a bit neater

Comment: @John no problem..